# Ubuntu 12.10 flickering with AMD Radeon HD 6625M

Tags: 12.10, upgrade, ati, graphics

I let my the software update update the kernel. but when it restarted, it started to flicker and flash the screen. I can only hear the login screen sound. I can restore this by selecting the old kernel from grub. How do I fix it? Or at least someone tell me how to make it boot from the old kernel automatically.

Comment: Can you give us the version of the non working linux kernel. Of the output of `dpkg --list | grep linux-image`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try editing the Grub boot menu. Look for "gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode". If you have this try changing it to "gfxmode 800x600" to force the boot resolution to a value which is more likely to work.

If you are having this problem on a laptop then for a quick fix try closing the lid to send it to "Sleep" then open it again after a few seconds to wake it up. You should then see the login screen.

For any newbies, I have posted a more detailed explanation of the steps required to modify this entry in your Grub menu at [Screen flickering in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156329/screen-flickering-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts/303131#303131).

Comment: the sleep thingy works on my laptop. this tearing does not happen when i'm using the radeon driver. it only occurs on fglrx drivers i have downloaded from amd. is there a permanent fix for this?